# How to fix - assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

I need to remove all the commas from my user input. The code is working but it's giving the warning "assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast". I need to get rid of this warning.

```
removeCommas(argv[1]);

printf("%s", argv[1]);

return 0;



    for(i=0; i<strlen(num); i++)
    {   
        c = *(num + i);
        if(c == 44)    
        {   
            *(num + i) = "";                                               
        }                        
    }       

return 0;
```

Comment: Can you share your full source code, or [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: The warning "assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast" should almost always be considered as an error. You might want to look into the [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) function. There is no such thing as "nothing", you actually want to delete all commas from the string. BTW don't write `44`, write `','`

Comment: Google "delete char from string c".

Comment: Since you don't post the variable declarations, the question can't be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work on a char by char basis. loop over your input string, search for the comma, and then override it with the remaining of the string:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"



int main()

{
    char num[100];
    strcpy(num, "abc,def,,a,");

    unsigned int i;
    char c;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(num); i++)
    {
        c = num[i];
        if (c == ',')
        {
            if (num[i + 1] == '\0')
                num[i] = '\0';
            else
            {               
                size_t s = strlen(num + i + 1);
                memmove(num + i, num + i + 1, s+1);

                --i;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note, that you will end with string with '\0' in the middle of it. This will lead to memory leak.

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz What does `\0` in a string has to do with memory leaks? Do you mean that the memory after this `\0` will be unused?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 
How to properly free memory reserved for string, if you don't know it's real lenght, and the terminating char is in the middle of it?

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz Exactly in the same way as you would free it if the `\0` wasn't there.

Comment: It is not the fix what OP wants.

Comment: @nivpeled This code doesn't handle consecutive commas.

Comment: ...and he behaviour of `strcpy` for overlapping strings is undefined. It may work as expected or it may not. [`memmove`](delete char from string c) should be used instead.

Comment: This answer is wrong, the usage of `strcpy` with overlapping buffers is undefined.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it works on my machine :) however you are technically correct; so I now updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
        *(num + i) = "";
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to assign here, but  double quotes (`""`) denotes `char *`.

If you wanted to remove `,`(ASCII 44) from the string it is not the way to do it. You need to shift all the chars after `,` until `\0` and terminate the string properly.

Comment: I'm just trying to replace the comma with nothing.

Comment: @Muttaki there is no such thing `nothing` in `c`. I mean you need to certain about character to be replaced with `,`.

Comment: add a 'j' variable which you only increment when NOT a comma, and change the "write nothing" to a copy from *(num+j) = *(num+i)

Answer (score -1):

Note that (if you are going to remove all comas from string), the resulting string may be shorter than source one. And there is no real "string" type in C - it's only array of chars.

I think, that proper way will be:

1. Count number of commas in source string
2. Calculate length of resulting string and reserve enough memory for it
3. Iterate throug characters of source string, and copy them to resulting string, if they are not commas